# Как добавить пробел в строке вывода числа?

Tags: java

Неправильно:

```
 System.out.println("Write action (buy, fill, take, remaining, exit): ");
```

Вывод:

```
Write action (buy, fill, take, remaining, exit): 
>buy
```

Правильно (пробел перед buy):

```
Write action (buy, fill, take, remaining, exit): 
> buy
```

---

Полный код:

```
System.out.println("Write action (buy, fill, take, remaining, exit): ");
//System.out.print("> ");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String action = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println();

if (action.equals("exit")) {System.exit(errCode);}
else if (action.equals("buy")) {
    System.out.println("What do you want to buy? 1 - espresso, 2 - latte, 3 - cappuccino, back - to main menu: ");
```

---

все, спасибо решилась проблема

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("Write action (buy, fill, take, remaining, exit): ");
System.out.print("> ");
//получаем action
```

Это же нужно было сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю почему ваш, приложенный в комментарии, код не работает:

```
System.out.println("Write action (buy, fill, take, remaining, exit): ");
System.out.print("> ");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String action = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println("Action: " + action);
```

Консоль:

```
Write action (buy, fill, take, remaining, exit): 
> buy
Action: buy
```

Answer (score -1):

Пробел можно было ввести простыми `" "`:  `System.out.print(a*n+" " + b*n);`

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/760349)

Comment: Ваш ответ по сути вообще никак не связан с вопросом.